# iOS diagnostics test gives you new problems?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari

Has anyone gotten software problems after performing the iOS diagnostics test offered by Apple? (where you get a test URL from Apple support)

I can't connect to Gmail on Safari after the test... it keeps reloading.
Logging out nor restarting is helping.
Anyone with similar problems?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried restarting the device? This will wipe the cache, and perhaps solve your problem.